# Compare Validator not working for ajax Calendar Extender

Tags: asp.net, ajax, c#-4.0, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have two text boxes that accept dates.I have used a compare validator that checks whether the date entered in second text box >= date entered in first text box.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblDate" Width="200px" Text="Date Posted:"></asp:Label></td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtDatePosted" runat="server" Width="200px" CausesValidation="true"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Width="16px" AlternateText="" ImageUrl="~/Image/cal.jpg" Height="16px" />
            <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="calExtDatePost" runat="server" Format="dd/MM/yyyy" PopupButtonID="btnCalenderPopup" PopupPosition="TopRight" TargetControlID="txtDatePosted" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblExpiryDate" Width="200px" Text="Expiry Date:"></asp:Label></td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtExpdate" runat="server" Width="200px" CausesValidation="true"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" Width="16px" AlternateText="" ImageUrl="~/Image/cal.jpg" Height="16px" />
            <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" Format="dd/MM/yyyy" PopupButtonID="btnCalenderPopup" PopupPosition="TopRight" TargetControlID="txtExpdate" />
            <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Expiry date must be greater than Posted date" ControlToCompare="txtDatePosted" ControlToValidate="txtExpdate" Operator="GreaterThanEqual" ValidationGroup="vsNewUser" Type="Date" Text="*Expiry date must be greater than Posted date"></asp:CompareValidator>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

But the validator is not working. It is always showing the error message. Please help me.

I know the compare validator takes the below format:

1/1/2001

1-1-2001

5/4/2012

And these two  text boxes accepts dates in the format like '27/07/2013'.

Comment: What version of ajaxcontroltoolkit you are using?

Comment: 4.1.7.607 is the file version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is not in Ajax Control Toolkit.

Your code is not working because `CompareValidator` uses `System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.ShortDatePattern` property to determine how to convert string to date. `CompareValidator` supports `ymd`, `mdy` and `dmy` date formats.

And to fix your issue you need to explicitly specify `Page.Culture` property that has `DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.ShortDatePattern` equal to `dd/MM/yyyy`. For example `en-GB`.